# android 8 and 10 SecurityException reading images in media store

Tags: android, android-permissions

Step 1. ChatFragment launches Android file Picker

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, RequestCode.PICK_PHOTO_GALLERY_CHAT)
```

Step 2. ChatFragment get the image Uri from the result, pass it to the next FullscreenPhotoActivity

```
@Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent extra) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, extra);

    switch (requestCode) {
      case RequestCode.PICK_PHOTO_GALLERY_CHAT:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
          Intent fullscreenPhoto = new Intent(getActivity(), FullscreenPhotoActivity.class);
          String imageUri = extra.getData().toString();
          fullscreenPhoto.putExtra(Extra.IMAGE_URI, imageUri);
          startActivityForResult(fullscreenPhoto, RequestCode.PICK_PHOTO_CONFIRMATION);
        }
        break;
```

Step 3. User confirms the image is Ok, FullscreenPhotoActivity passes the Uri back to ChatFragment, ChatFragment try to open the image given the same Uri but `SecurityException` thrown

```
case RequestCode.PICK_PHOTO_CONFIRMATION:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
          final Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(data.getStringExtra(Extra.IMAGE_URI));
          inputStream = context.get().getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);// SECURITY EXCEPTION
          //...
        }
        break;
```

Crash stacktrace for android 8.1.0:

```
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.impl.MediaContentProvider from ProcessRecord{9fe5054 14588:com.myapp/u0a195} (pid=14588, uid=10195) that is not exported from UID 10146
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2021)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1967)
       at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProvider(IActivityManager.java:5228)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:6181)
       at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2676)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1786)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1400)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1253)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:973)
       at com.myapp.feature.chat.ChatPresenter$PhotoToSendAsyncTask.doInBackground(ChatPresenter.java:485)
       at com.myapp.feature.chat.ChatPresenter$PhotoToSendAsyncTask.doInBackground(ChatPresenter.java:456)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

And for 10

```
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: com.myapp has no access to content://media/external/images/media/29763
       at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2088)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2056)
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188)
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:151)
       at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderProxy.java:705)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1694)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1510)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1194)
       at com.myapp.feature.chat.ChatPresenter$PhotoToSendAsyncTask.doInBackground(ChatPresenter.java:470)
       at com.myapp.feature.chat.ChatPresenter$PhotoToSendAsyncTask.doInBackground(ChatPresenter.java:441)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And of course my app requests `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` at runtime too

Comment: Those permissions have nothing to do with your crashes. Those permissions are for files. Your crashes are coming from content `Uri` values. Where are you getting those `Uri` values from, and when are you trying to use them? Are you trying to use them across multiple activities or processes?

Answer (score 0):

Are your images locate in external SD card? I've similar problem, only occur for files in external SD card.